# How to read annotation value in play framework templates?

Tags: java, playframework

I want to use values from annotation in CRUD module templates, to utilize HTML5 functions.

e.g.

@Range(min=0, max=10)

public int size;

CRUD module use views/tags/crud/numberField.html to display number field:

```
#{field 'object.' + _name}
    <label for="${field.id}">
        &{_name}
    </label>
    <input id="${field.id}" type="text" name="${field.name}" value="${params[field.name]?.escape()?.raw() ?: field.error?.message == 'validation.required' ? '' : _value?.escape()?.raw()}" size="5" />
    #{ifError field.name}
        <span class="error">${field.error}</span>
    #{/ifError}
#{/field}
```

How can I read min/max value from annotation then output as min="0" max="0" in <input> ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by adding methods to the CRUD module's `CRUD.ObjectType.ObjectField` inner class that read the annotation values, e.g. something like:

```
public String getRangeMin() {
    if (!property.field.isAnnotationPresent(Range.class)) {
        return null;
    }
    return property.field.getAnnotation(Range.class).min();
}
```

Then in `crud/views/tags/crud/form.html` you can use this in a new tag parameter inside the `#{if field.type == 'number'}` (note that `field` is a `CRUD.ObjectType.ObjectField` here:

```
#{crud.numberField min:field.min …
```

The value is then available as `_min` inside the `numberField.html` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write a [FastTag](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1.1/templates#fasttags) for that. Since this is all Java you can use reflection to query your objects for annotations in there. If you want to use it exclusive for validation you could let the [html5validation](http://www.playframework.org/modules/html5validation-1.1/home#Example) module to do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

in the Validation sample included in Play!, Sample #7 includes some Jquery code that reads the annotations in a class and uses them for Javascript validation. I believe that should help you.